# Class.getResource and ClassLoader.getSystemResource: is there a reason to prefer one to another?

Tags: java, resources

I saw both `Class.getResource` and `ClassLoader.getSystemResource` used to locate a resource in Java. Is there any reason to prefer one to another?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are several ways to load resources, each with a slightly different meaning -

`ClassLoader::getSystemResource()` uses the system classloader. This uses the classpath that was used to start the program. If you are in a web container such as tomcat, this will NOT pick up resources from your WAR file.

`Class<T>#getResource()` prepends the package name of the class to the resource name, and then delegates to its classloader. If your resources are stored in a package hierarchy that mirrors your classes, use this method.

`ClassLoader#getResource()` delegates to its parent classloader. This will eventually search for the resource all the way upto the system classloader.

If you are confused, just stick to `ClassLoader#getResource()`

Answer (score 4):

From [`Class.getResource( )`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

> This method delegates the call to its
>   class loader, after making these
>   changes to the resource name: if the
>   resource name starts with "/", it is
>   unchanged; otherwise, the package name
>   is prepended to the resource name
>   after converting "." to "/". If this
>   object was loaded by the bootstrap
>   loader, the call is delegated to
>   `ClassLoader.getSystemResource`.

and [`ClassLoader.getSystemResource( )`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource%28java.lang.String%29)

> Find a resource of the specified name
>   from the search path used to load
>   classes. This method locates the
>   resource through the system class
>   loader

Comment: A good answer would include information about how to discover where resources can be found

Answer (score 0):

`ClassLoader.getSystemResource()` will use the bootstrap (system) classloader.

`Class.getResource()` will use that particular instance of `Class`'s classloader, in other words whatever classloader was used to load that class.  This may be a different classloader than the system classloader.

Answer (score 0):

Using Methods of java.lang.Class:

```
public java.net.URL getResource(String name) {
  name = resolveName(name);
  ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
  if (cl==null) {
    return ClassLoader.getSystemResource(name);  // A system class.
  }
  return cl.getResource(name);
}
```