# Read a file within a jar from java code present in same jar

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I am trying to read a xsd file kept in a jar using java code kept inside the same jar. I am using the following code.

```
URL tmpurl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/abc/filename.xsd");

Schema s = schemaFactory.newSchema(tmpurl);
jaxbUnMarshaller.setSchema(s);
```

It is working fine when I run it as a separate project but when I make a jar, tmpurl is null, hence the setSchema gives a null pointer exception.

Can you please a workaround that can make it run even inside a jar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hava you tried?

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()
```

Also your `classpath` in manifest file in jar does matter.

Please, take a look at accepted answers in here:

[Class.getResource and ClassLoader.getSystemResource: is there a reason to prefer one to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298400/class-getresource-and-classloader-getsystemresource-is-there-a-reason-to-prefer)

[Loading files with ClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119740/loading-files-with-classloader)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, whatever you pointed out was absolutely correct and the given links were also helpful and informative.