# Access Resources in Unit Tests

Tags: java, gradle, junit4

I'm using JUnit 4, Java 8, and Gradle 1.12.
I have a file with default json that I need to load. My project has `src/main/java/` (containing the project source), `src/main/resources/` (empty), `src/test/java/` (unit test source), and `src/test/resources/` (the json data file to load) directories. The `build.gradle` file is in the root.

In my code I have:

```
public class UnitTests extends JerseyTest
{
  @Test
  public void test1() throws IOException
  {
    String json = UnitTests.readResource("/testData.json");
    // Do stuff ...
  }

  // ...
  private static String readResource(String resource) throws IOException
  {
    // I had these three lines combined, but separated them to find the null.
    ClassLoader c = UnitTests.class.getClassLoader();
    URL r = c.getSystemResource(resource); // This is returning null. ????
    //URL r = c.getResource(resource); // This had the same issue.
    String fileName = r.getFile();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)))
    {
      StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
      char[] buf = new char[1024];
      int readCount = 0;
      while ((readCount = reader.read(buf)) != -1)
      {
        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, readCount);
        fileData.append(readData);
      }

      return fileData.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

From what I read, that should give me access to the resource file. However, I get a null pointer exception when I try to use the URL, because the `getSystemResource()` call returns null.

How do I access my resource files?

Comment: Do you have the /src/test/resources folder in your classpath?

Comment: I doubt it. I'm not loading classes though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resource names don't start with a slash, so you'll need to get rid of that. The resource should preferably be read with `UnitTests.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("the/resource/name")`, or, if a `File` is required, `new File(UnitTests.getClassLoader().getResource("the/resource/name").toURI())`.

On Java 8, you could try something like:

```
URI uri = UnitTests.class.getClassLoader().getResource("the/resource/name").toURI();
String string = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(uri)), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Comment: The issue was the slash. All of the examples I read had a leading slash for some reason.  The Java 8 suggestion has some bugs. Here's the correct code, for anyone using this: `URI uri = UnitTests.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resource).toURI();
return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(uri)), Charset.forName("utf-8"));`

Comment: Either the examples were using `Class#getResource` rather than `ClassLoader#getResource`, or they were wrong. Fixed the Java 8 code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want getResource instead of getSystemResource.  The latter is used to, for example, read a file from the file system, where the path would not be specified in terms of the jar.

You can also skip the class loader: `UnitTests.class.getResource("...")`

[Docs about resources here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)

**Edit**: there are some more detailed comments in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6298400/411282).

Comment: I was using getResources, but it produces the same error.

Comment: After reading more carefully, I realize I misunderstood the getSystemResource docs.  Its argument is specified in terms of the system environment's classpath, not the file system root, as I was thinking when I wrote the answer above.  I'll leave the answer here for the sake of the links.