# getResource() nullPointerException

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I am trying to get the contents of a local JSON file in Java. Instead I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    fi.avaliaho.ottoautomaatitv2.Webservice.doGet(Webservice.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:352)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:171)
```

I already made sure that the file `coordinates.json` is located in the same directory as the `Webservice.java` file. I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301329/java-class-getresource-returns-null), but the answers do not solve my problem. Here is my servlet:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Webservice extends HttpServlet {

    URL path = null;
    Reader file = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        path = Webservice.class.getResource("coordinates.json");
        file = new FileReader(path.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried prepending / like `Webservice.class.getResource("/coordinates.json")`?

Comment: `I already made sure that the file coordinates.json is located in the same directory as the Webservice.java`. Is the class-file located in the same directory as the source? If not put the json-file into the directory where the classes are (that's where the class path in general points to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `getSystemResource()` method

```
path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("coordinates.json")
```

or how it was mentioned by @LaksithaRanasingha in comments add `/` in the begining:

```
path = Webservice.class.getResource("/coordinates.json");
```

Also this might be useful [Class.getResource and ClassLoader.getSystemResource: is there a reason to prefer one to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298400/class-getresource-and-classloader-getsystemresource-is-there-a-reason-to-prefer)