# Java - java.io.File with Classpath

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception, classpath

I need to use/define a `java.io.File` variable type to get a file that is going to be send as parameter to another method.

Now I have with relative path:

```
File file = new File("C:/javaproject/src/main/resources/demo/test.txt");
```

I want to change it using `ClassLoader` like this:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/demo/test.txt");
```

But I cannot use it into File because is not the same type. If I use `.toString()` it returns NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

And when I print it with a System output return the same, an exception:
    System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("demo/test.txt").toString());

**Both, folder and file exists.** Why that error?

Comment: try ``ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/demo/test.txt")`` (with a slash at the beginning)

Comment: The same error @spi

Comment: ``URL url = getClass().getResource("/demo/test.txt")``

Comment: from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource(java.lang.String)) it returns a URL object for reading the resource, or null if the resource could not be found. So you are inputing a wrong "name" so it's returning null causing the NullPointerException when you try to do null.toString()

Comment: Just a hint: `C:/javaproject/src/main/resources/demo/test.txt` is **not** a relative path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
try {
    URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("demo/test.txt");
    if (nonNull(resource)) {
        File file = new File(resource.toURI());
        // do something
    }
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error while reading file", e);
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298400/class-getresource-and-classloader-getsystemresource-is-there-a-reason-to-prefer) shows the different between `ClassLoader.getSystemResource` and `getClassLoader().getResource()`